# What's the difference between following 4 styles call other member method?

Tags: c++

What's the difference between the following 4 styles of calling another member function?

Is there a benefit that causes that one method is preferrable?

```
void Object::trigger() {
  (*this).triggerinner(10);
  this->triggerinner(10);
  triggerinner(10);
  Object::triggerinner(10);
}

void Object::triggerinner(int x) {
  std::cout << "trigger" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The best is the simplest: `triggerinner(10;`. However, in some cases, with inheritance involving class templates, you might need to use `this` or `BaseClass::methodName(....);`

Comment: Unless you must use a specific syntax (as mentioned in the comment by juanchopanza) this is very much based on personal preference.

Comment: Also, when posting code, **don't** post images of the code, copy-paste the code into the question and format it properly instead.

Answer (score 4):

The first three are fundamentally the same in non-template code.
In a template member function, the first two make the name
lookup dependent (so the compiler can find names in a dependent
base class).  Generally, simpler is better, so most people favor
the third form, except when the dependend lookup is necessary,
in which case they will use the second.

The fourth form blocks virtual resolution.  (And it has, in
fact, the same three forms as above, i.e.
`this->Object::triggerinner(10)`, etc.)  You use it when you
want to force the resolution: the function called will be in
`Object` or in a base class of `Object`, but never in a derived
class, even if the function is virtual.  This is most often used
in a derived class, to call the base class implementation before
(or after) doing additional work:

```
void
Derived::func()
{
    Base::func();
    //  Additional work here...
}
```

Outside of a member function, it can also be used to call
a static member function when you don't have an object.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are exactly equivalent to each other. By definition, `(*p).thing` and `p->thing` are equivalent for any pointer.

The third is equivalent in this situation; but could have a different meaning if the member function's name were hidden by a local declaration. There are also situations (where the function is a member of a base class, and templates are involved) when this form won't find the function, in which case you would have to use one of the others.

The fourth is equivalent if the function is not virtual. If it is virtual, then this will force a non-virtual call to the override available in this class, rather than the final override.

Answer (score 0):

```
(*this).triggerinner(10);
```

It's ugly, "->" is there to avoid to do that.

```
this->triggerinner(10);
```

It's fine but `this->` is not mandatory. If you are working on an existing project, keep the current coding style.

```
triggerinner(10);
```

It's fine, same comment than the solution using `this->`.

```
Object::triggerinner(10);
```

Use this for static methods.

I would suggest you to use `triggerinner(10)` since it's short and clear.

Comment: is the last style can work? do you mean it isn't one good style for non-static method call?

Comment: @jiafu: The last style prevents the function from being called virtually, by specifying exactly which override to call. You should only use it if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

the most frequently used one is this->triggerinner(10);.The reason it makes an easy match using the pointer with table.

Comment: I would argue the most frequently used one is the simplest one: `triggerinner(10);`. But such generalising statements are pretty mucn pointless. It depends on project coding style, actually.

Answer (score -1):

`this->triggerinner(10)` is better than the others:

1. Better than `(*this).triggerinner(10)` because it is more readable.
2. better than `triggerinner(10)`, because in this case you will not know if `triggerinner()` is a method or a function (with a different scope then).
3. Better than `Object::triggerinner(10)` which is mainly used for static methods (but not only)

Comment: The general consensus is to prefer the simpler `triggerinner(10)` when it will work.  (The semantics of the four calls are not exactly identical, and there are cases when one or the other cannot be used.)

Comment: It is a bad idea, due to the " `when it will work` ".

Comment: Please explain the downvote (and not use the "general consensus" to argue).

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference, unless your compiler does some funky stuff. Try reading the assembly language generated by the lines in your function and see if there are any differences or if its the same block of instructions generated over and over.

As for the "best" or " most popular" one that comes down to your personal preference or when working at a company they might enforce certain coding standards forcing you to write in a specific way when doing something every time.

Comment: -1: There is a difference ineed, if `triggerinner` is virtual. In such case, the virtual dispatch will be circumvented by the 4th version.

Comment: The last doesn't have the same semantics as the first three, and the first two are different from the third in a template.

Comment: Where "funky stuff" includes standard language features like templates, virtual functions and name hiding, all of which could make a difference here.

Comment: I never knew about any of that. Informative, thank you!